# Multiple column/row form that is editable by multiple users

Tags: apex, visualforce

So hope someone can help!

Problem Scope :I am a new system administrator looking to implement a custom opportunity page layout that allows one set of SF users to request Quote for up to 20 products and another set to SF users to act on the request to convert the quote into an order.

Specific Issue : I am able to design a page layout to capture 1 product quote request. But how can a users request for 20 lines quote? This is the question I asked SF and the answer was Visual Force. 
So now I need to create a VF page that will capture 30 custom fields created in my new page layout and facilitate the users to populate the same information for 20 different products i.e. capturing 600 fields worth of content. Is this even possible?

Cheers
Snitha

Comment: Hi Snitha, welcome to SFSE. You post great questions, but I think you will get better attention and answers, if you post each question as a separate post. SFSE is unlike a forum, it's more of a Q&A site, thus, answering multiple questions in the same post is tricky for all.

Comment: Point Noted! Will break them down.

Comment: remember you can edit the original post, to have a single question as a start.